# How to link two different products to each other

Tags: product, configurable-product, product-list

I'd like to link two different products with each other and within some options. Like this:

Product A (`productA.html`) and Product B (`productB.html`) link to each other by (for example) color: Product A is black, Product B is white. I want both products to remain separate products with separate product pages. So there is no configuration, just a box where you can see both products by color.

Each product has its own options. So for example:

Product A

- Original
- Not Original

Product B

- Original
- Maybe Original
- Not Original

How would I do something like this?

Answer (score 2):

**Just add related products for each product.**

Or create a configurable product, add a module to reverse lookup relations for the configurable product, and show the other products.

```
$otherProducts = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
/** @var $otherProducts Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */

$select = $otherProducts->getSelect();

$select->join(array('pr' => $otherProducts->getTable('catalog/product_relation')), 'e.entity_id = pr.child_id', array())
    ->join(array('pr2' => $otherProducts->getTable('catalog/product_relation')), 'pr.parent_id = pr2.parent_id', array())
    ->where('pr2.child_id = ?', $product->getId())
    ->where('pr.child_id != ?', $product->getId())
    ->group('e.entity_id');

var_dump($otherProducts->getAllIds());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your looking for here, it sounds like your looking to setup a configurable product i.e. Product A and Product B are the same type of item but they are distinguished by the product colour or some other attributes.

When you create a new configurable you can set the visible scope of the generated simple product. If you keep this visible you would be able to directly access the product variant page. This simple product could be named and provided with detailed description and product images as a normal product would.